# VB My.Settings Configuration Error Exception

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a form where I want to save a list of values to My.Settings. In the form, changes will be made to the list and when I close the form, the updated list will be saved to  the settings. The next time I start the form my list will get the values from My.Settings.

This is what I have done so far.
To load the list from the settings:

```
Dim fl As New List(Of String)
For Each Item As String In My.Settings.foodlist
            fl.Add(Item)
        Next
```

And then to save the list into settings on closing the form:

```
My.Settings.foodlist.Clear()
For Each Item As String In fl
   My.Settings.foodlist.Add(Item)
Next
My.Settings.Save()
Form1.Close()
```

In my project settings, I have defined foodlist as a system.collection.specialized.stringcollection. The scope is set to user, and the value is currently blank.

However, when I run, I receive an error which says **System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'**
ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.diagnostics. (C:\Users\samsj\Downloads\EatWhat_webversion\WinFormsApp_22Feb\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\EatWhat_webver.dll.config line 5)

In particular, the line that seems to have an issue is

```
Return CType(Me("foodlist"), Global.System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this after looking through suggestions from another forum. I went to my dll.config file and deleted the entire system.diagnostics code:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
        <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="FileLog"/>
                <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="FileLog"
             type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
             initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
        <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I have absolutely no idea why deleting this code works, since I assumed that this is a default code.